# What happened to my airplant, can it be revived?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care

I recently purchased this airplant online, when I received it it was healthy and green. The directions said to water once a week, I may have gone over that amount before watering. Is this plant revivable? Will soaking it in water help? Or is this a total lost? [image: airplant][image: airplant]
[image: airplant]

The environment I have it in includes rocks, moss and it's inside an open glass container.

Comment: Looks like rot, tillandsia like bright diffuse light and high humidity but not wet feet.

Comment: That may have been the problem then. No humidity. @kevinsky

Comment: If you have an environment that is humid and well lit, like a bathroom window, move it there

Comment: When you write that you have 'recently bought this on line' how recently? If only a week or two before you took this picture, I'd ask for a replacement and expect one to be sent.

Answer (score 2):

It looks irretrievable with all the leaves rotting.

As you said, you over watered it. It's important to make sure after watering it does dry out otherwise fungal and bacterial infections can take hold. Also you should use rain water, and not tap water as chlorinated water can also do this.

The leaves are the only part that needs watering as water is taken up in a  specialized leaf structure. There is no need to get water on the root.

Answer (score 2):

total loss...=(...i had several airplants that were overwatered and i didn't even know it.  i just followed what i was told when i first bought it.  the one that works well for me is the misting and a quick wash..soaking didn't work for the plants .